# How to set template for each column item in ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I want to set template for item according to column.Clearly,set template for something like GridViewColumn.ItemTemplate  .Is there are any possibilty to do that?Fisrt i used ListBox,but for some reasons i go to listView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplate1">
        <Grid>
            …
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>    
    <DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplate2">
        <Grid>
            …
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplate3">
        <Grid>
            …
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.Resources>

<DataGrid.Columns>                
    <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource cellTemplate1}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource cellTemplate2}" />
    <DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource cellTemplate3}" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

cellTemplate1 will be template for the whole first column, cellTemplate2 - for second column, etc.

Comment: it will change only cell template not items in it

Comment: ooookay..... can you describe what do you want to 'put' into your datagrid's row? (with description of each column)

Comment: i have item which contains name and info.i must show name with icon according to name(at left).and info at right.And all these must be columned

Comment: and what's the problem?)

you can define your first column like this:
    `<DataTemplate x:Key="cellTemplate1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image ... />
            <TextBlock ... />
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel >
    </DataTemplate> `

as second column you can use DataGridTextColumn

Answer (score 0):

You can do this but setting the `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate` property.... its lets you make the `Column` the way you want it to be.. :)

```
    <ListView Name="lv"
                       ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyFavList}">
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                      <!--Your Fav Controls-->
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>

    </ListView >
```

I think this should solver problem... :) although DataGrid is a better choice as far as out of the box functionality is concerned.... ;)